# Why external struct is called two times in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I was surprised why my struct is called two times! Can anybody please explain the issue? No need to bypass the issue, just curious why does it happen?

```
struct PerformanceTest: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Next Page")) {
                ButtonView()
                myPrint("test----15------") //called once
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ButtonView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            myPrint("test----16------") //why is it called two times!
            Text("Oxygen")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func myPrint(_ vars: Any...) -> some View {
        for v in vars { print(v) }
        return EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Comment: i just found out it has something to do with navigationlink - without it it is just called once

Comment: @Chris Yes I have seen that. But you see, log inside NavigationLink is called only once!

Comment: yes i have seen and also no idea why... ;)